# Lower bound for cyclic expression in four variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

We are given four positive real numbers $a,b,c,d$. I would like to prove that
$$\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac cd+\frac da\ge4$$
To start solving this I assumed
$$a\ge b\ge c\ge d$$
Therefore
$$\frac ab,\frac bc,\frac cd\ge 1,\ \frac da\le 1$$
and the last one is causing the problem.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: to prove the above.

Comment: Use AM GM inequality

Comment: Is $a\geq b\geq c\geq d$ part of the questions definitions?

Comment: no. i assumed it

Comment: For the "other side" inequality see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56395/prove-that-frac4abcd-geq-frac-a-b-frac-bc-frac-cd-frac-d-a).

Answer (score 5):

As lab bhattacharjee commented, You can use the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). By applying it here, we can obtain:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{d} + \frac{d}{a}}{4} & \ge \sqrt[4]{\frac{abcd}{bcda}}\\
& = \sqrt[4]{1}\\
& = 1
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore:

$$
\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{d} + \frac{d}{a} \ge 4
$$