# Use AM-GM to prove this inequality

Tags: inequality

I need to prove this inequality using AM-GM. Any help would be appreciated.

> Let $a, b, c, d$ be non-negative numbers such that    $a +b + c + d = 4$. Prove that:
>   $$\frac4{abcd} \ge \frac ab +   \frac bc +  \frac cd +  \frac da$$

Comment: Are you sure it is possible? Your inequality is cyclic, but not symmetric. If there are multiple stationary points (besides the one at $(1,1,1,1)$) the AM-GM inequality might be not powerful enough to prove the claim. Power mean inequalities tend to work only if there is a single stationary point.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56395/prove-that-frac4abcd-geq-frac-a-b-frac-bc-frac-cd-frac-d-a?rq=1

Comment: Note that the above link shows that this is a duplicate