# Prove that $\frac{a}{1+b^2c}+\frac{b}{1+c^2d}+\frac{c}{1+d^2a}+\frac{d}{1+a^2b}\ge 2$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Given $a+b+c+d=4, $ and $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers. Prove that  $$\frac{a}{1+b^2c}+\frac{b}{1+c^2d}+\frac{c}{1+d^2a}+\frac{d}{1+a^2b}\ge 2$$

Can someone give me hints for this?

To show

$$\frac{a^2}{a+b^2ca}+\frac{b^2}{b+c^2db}+\frac{c^2}{c+d^2ac}+\frac{d^2}{d+a^2bd}\ge 2\implies \frac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{a+b^2ca+b+c^2db+c+d^2ac+d+a^2bd}$$
$$\implies \frac{16}{4+ b^2ca+ c^2db+ d^2ac+ a^2bd}\ge 2.$$

It is enough to show that $$ \frac{8}{4+ b^2ca+ c^2db+ d^2ac+ a^2bd}\ge 1.$$

Comment: Note that the last inequality isn't true (EG $a=2, b=1, c = 1/2, d = 1$), so you've loosened it too much.

Comment: @CalvinLin so maybe I should show $${a+b^2ca+b+c^2db+c+d^2ac+d+a^2bd}\ge 8$$

Comment: That is a true statement (do you see why?), but I'm not sure how it helps your original inequality.

Comment: @CalvinLin woopsie, I wrote the problem statement wrong

Comment: Problem statement seems fine to me (inequality is in the right direction).

Comment: @SunainaPati The condition should be $abcd = 1$.

Comment: @RiverLi nope it should be $a+b+c+d=4.$ The book said..

Comment: Yes, with $a+b+c+d=4$ it's just Rearrangement

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg would u like to explain how? I am not sure..

Comment: I have found something nicer! See my post. I am writing it during my lecture. After one hour. OK?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Does we have $$\frac{a}{1+b^{2}c}+\frac{b}{1+c^{2}d}+\frac{c}{1+d^{2}a}+\frac{d}{1+a^{2}b}\geq \frac{a}{1+\left(abcd\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}}+\frac{b}{1+\left(abcd\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}}+\frac{c}{1+\left(abcd\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}}+\frac{d}{1+\left(abcd\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}}$$ for $a,b,c,d>0$ such that $a+b+c+d=4$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\frac4{abcd} \geq \frac a b + \frac bc + \frac cd +\frac d a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56395/prove-that-frac4abcd-geq-frac-a-b-frac-bc-frac-cd-frac-d-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to prove that:
$$a^2bd+b^2ca+c^2bd+d^2ac\leq4,$$
Now, use AM-GM twice.

Comment: I got it! thanks!

Comment: or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56395/prove-that-frac4abcd-geq-frac-a-b-frac-bc-frac-cd-frac-d-a?rq=1